# Storing data to array from JSON response

Tags: axios, google-places-api, dialogflow-es

I am calling google Places API which returns a JSON response similar to this, from this responss I would like to extract all the name objects and store them in an array:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "next_page_token" : "CpQCAgEAAFxg8o-eU7_uKn7Yqjana-",
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.867217,
               "lng" : 151.195939
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/cafe-71.png",
         "id" : "7eaf747a3f6dc078868cd65efc8d3bc62fff77d7",
         "name" : "Biaggio Cafe - Pyrmont",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 600,
               "html_attributions" : [],
               "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAAmWmj0BqA0Jorm1_vjAvx1n6c7ZNBxyY-U9x99-oNyIBE",
               "width" : 900
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJIfBAsjeuEmsRdgu9Pl1Ps48",
         "price_level" : 1,
         "types" : [ "cafe", "bar", "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.866786,
               "lng" : 151.195633
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png",
         "id" : "3ef986cd56bb3408bc1cf394f3dad9657c1d30f6",
         "name" : "Doltone House",
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 1260,
               "html_attributions" : [ "From a Google User" ],
               "photo_reference" : "CnRwAAAAeM-ag",
               "width" : 1890
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJ5xQ7szeuEmsRs6Kj7YFZE9k",
         "reference" : "CnRvAAAA22k1PAGyDxAgHZk6ErHh_h_mLUK_8XNFLvixPJHXRbCzg-",
         "types" : [ "food", "establishment" ],
         "vicinity" : "48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont"
      },
      {
         "aspects" : [
            {
               "rating" : 23,
               "type" : "overall"
            }
         ],
      ...
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

In my code, I would like to store all instances of name in an array. I'm not really sure how to do this, but what I'm doing right now is definitely not working, the array remains empty after console logging it.

```
var place_search = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=" + encodeURIComponent(agent.parameters.cuisine) + "restaurant" + "&region=sg&location=" + lat + "," + long + "&radius=" + user_proximity + "&opennow" + "&key=" + api_key;
     return axios.get(place_search)
     .then(response => {
    const { place_id, name, formatted_address } = response.data.results;
    placeArray.push({
      name: name,
      place_id: place_id    
    });
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your code, and it isn't clear what you think each part is trying to do, but the biggest issue seems to be with how you're handling the call with axios inside the loop. In particular, there seem to be two issues:

- You're returning the value from the call - this breaks out of the loop after executing the `then` portion the first time.
- Related to this, the code after the `return` can't get executed (you've returned from the function), so you never evaluate if the rating is greater than 4.

Assuming you're trying to loop through the places in `placeArray` and make a network call with axios for each one, you may want to use `await`, which is available in more modern versions of node. It might look something like this:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < placeArray.length; i++) {
     var place_details = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=" + placeArray[i].place_id + "&fields=rating&key=" + api_key;
     const response = await axios.get(place_details);
     const ratings = response.data.result.rating;
     if (ratings > 4 ){
       agent.add(`Ok I recommend ` + JSON.stringify(placeArray[i].name) + ` and the address is ` + JSON.stringify(placeArray[i].formatted_address));
       agent.add(`It is rated ` + placeArray[i].ratings )
       break;
     }
   }
```

Comment: That's helpful, thanks very much. I've changed that part of my code accordingly. Do you see any issue with the storing of the json response in this bit?                  
 const { place_id, name, formatted_address } = response.data.results;
       placeArray.push({ place_id, name, formatted_address });

Comment: I'm having some issues with it, the array remains empty even after the push.

Comment: Please update your original question if you're clarifying your question - trying to follow code changes in comments can be very difficult. It also helps to clarify what issues you're having, why you think it isn't working, and any other debugging you may have done to try and figure out the problem yourself (for example - what `response` or `response.data` contains).